# Mockito, how to verify parameters of ther method in the last time it was called

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

During executing unit test the method is called 3 times. Each time it's called with different parameters. I want to verify, that on the last time method was called with corresponding paramets.

Please, help me.

My method :

```
private void doHandle(Updategram updategram)
      throws FixtureNotFoundException, DatatypeConfigurationException {
    BetSyncObject betSyncObject = transformer.transformer(updategram);
    EventTreeCreation event = betSyncObject.eventTree;
    if (!event.getEvent().isEmpty()) {
      Event event2 = event.getEvent().get(0);
      long timestamp =
          updategram.getHeader().getTimeStampUtc().toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();
      String sportName = event2.getSportcode();
      String id = event2.getExtId();
      publisher.publishEvent(PROVIDER_NAME, betSyncObject, sportName, id, timestamp);
    } else {
      LOGGER.info("Empty event tree : {}", betSyncObject);
    }
  }
```

Test:

```
 @Test
    public void testCountAndSetResultLine() throws Exception{
        EventPublisher eventPublisher = Mockito.mock(EventPublisher.class);
        BetgeniusService betgeniusService = new BetgeniusService();

        BetSyncObject expectedBetSyncObj = transformer.transformer(updategram);

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        handle(betgeniusService, updategramFixture, service);
        Thread.sleep(50);
        handle(betgeniusService, updategramMarketSet, service);
        Thread.sleep(50);
        handle(betgeniusService, updategramResult, service);

        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        betgeniusService.getExecutor().shutdown();
        betgeniusService.getExecutor().awaitTermination(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        Mockito.verify(eventPublisher, Mockito.times(3)).publishEvent(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(BetSyncObject.class),
                Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyLong());

    }
```

For this moment I am getting exception, because the `publishEvent` method is not called 3 times with exactly `expectedBetSyncObj`. It should be called with it only last time.

So, please tell how could I check that the `publishEvent` method was called with the `expectedBetSyncObj`  object the last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with an [ArgumentCaptor](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html).
Use the ArgumentCaptor to get the arguments for all calls made and then later verify each one of them.
In your case you would verify that on the third call the argument (`.get(2)`) is the expected object.

So something like

```
ArgumentCaptor<BetSyncObject> betSyncObjectCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(BetSyncObject.class);
Mockito.verify(eventPublisher, Mockito.times(3)).publishEvent(Mockito.anyString(), betSyncObjectCaptor.capture(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyLong());

List<BetSyncObject> capturedBetSyncObject = betSyncObjectCaptor.getAllValues();
assertEquals(expectedBetSyncObj, capturedBetSyncObject.get(2));
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I need.

Comment: What is **expectedBetSyncObj**?